# What is the best way to optimze this query with indexes?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, key, explain

I have a table with about 30 million records which I need to perform queries upon. From my reading, I thought that a composite index using leftmost prefixing with all the fields I need to select would be the correct way to do it, but when I run an explain on the query, it's not even using the index.

This is the query:

```
select distinct email FROM my_table 
WHERE `customer_id` IN(278,428,186,40,208,247,59,79,376,73,38,52,68,227) 
AND `company_id` = 4 
AND `active` = 1 
AND `date` > '2012-04-15';
```

The explain looks like this

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | emails | index | customer_id   | email | 772     | NULL | 29296705 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

These are the fields

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
`company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',                                                                                                                                            
`date` date DEFAULT NULL
```

Indexes looks like this

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`,`customer_id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                
KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`,`company_id`,`active`,`date`)
```

I'm not quite sure what the best way to optimize this is.

Comment: @radashk The query only returns 3,117,636 rows. In the explain, it's showing that there are almost 30 million rows it needs to filter through.

Comment: those are all the occurences you use the WHERE IN clause. It cannot index that.

Comment: there's no one way or best way to improve performance, you have to go for different ways until you find your best solution

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is often fussy about `IN` on the left side of the index.  Try one query for each `customer_id` and see if that's using your index.  You can use the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) syntax to join them together  The other possibility is that MySQL figures it's faster to sift through everything for 10% of rows than to try to use indexes for them.

Comment: It did in fact use the index when I did that. I noticed also if I do a force index(customer_id), the explain will only show 6.3 million, which is a huge improvement.

Comment: I'd time the two queries, run each several times.  MySQL thinks it'll be faster not to use the index and it could be right.

Comment: Ran both queries 5 times each, and using FORCE INDEX is definitely an improvement. The times for the original query were 26.4, 25.4, 27.7, 25.1, and 25.5. The times for the FORCE INDEX query were 14.1, 14.3, 14.3, 13.9, and 14.9.

Comment: So, MySQl isn't doing the best thing by default and you'll have to help it with the `FORCE INDEX`.  As a last ditch effort, you could try running an `ANALYZE TABLE` to see if that helps it pick the index by default.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html